# Как получить событие мыши MouseMove из TabControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, tabcontrol, mousemove

Задача состоит в том, что при движении мыши по `ListBox` должно следовать перекрестие из двух пересекающихся линий.
Код Xaml:

```
<TabControl x:Name="Drawing_TabControl"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Background="WhiteSmoke"
                        SelectionChanged="Drawing_TabControl_SelectionChanged"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Files}"
                        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFile_M}"
                        MouseLeftButtonDown="Drawing_TabControl_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                        MouseMove="Drawing_TabControl_MouseMove"
                        MouseLeftButtonUp="Drawing_TabControl_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local1:File_M}">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Background="Transparent">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name_File}" Background="Transparent" />
                            <Button Height="18"
                                    Width="18"
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    BorderBrush="Transparent"
                                    Click="Close_TabItem"
                                    Visibility="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem},
                                                 Converter={StaticResource B2V}}">
                                <Image  Source="icons\close_x.png"/>
                            </Button>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local1:File_M}">
                        <Grid Background="WhiteSmoke">
                                <ListBox x:Name="a"
                                         Background="GhostWhite"
                                         Height="6cm"
                                         Width="16cm"
                                         HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                         VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Figures}"
                                         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFigure_M}"
                                         Tag="listbox">
                                    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                            <Canvas />
                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local2:Figure_M}">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Line x:Name="hor"
                                                      X1="0"
                                                      Y1="{Binding Path=YMove}"
                                                      X2="500"
                                                      Y2="{Binding Path=YMove}"
                                                      Stroke="DarkRed"
                                                      StrokeThickness="0.5" />
                                                <Line x:Name="ver"
                                                      X1="{Binding Path=XMove}"
                                                      Y1="0"
                                                      X2="{Binding Path=XMove}"
                                                      Y2="100"
                                                      Stroke="DarkRed"
                                                      StrokeThickness="0.5" />
                                            </Grid>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                </ListBox>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

            </TabControl>
```

Код c#

```
private void Drawing_TabControl_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            tag = "listbox";
            var figure_M = sender as Figure_M;

                figure_M.XMove = e.GetPosition(Drawing_TabControl).X;
                figure_M.YMove = e.GetPosition(Drawing_TabControl).Y;

        }
```

В данный момент выкидывает исключение при наведении мыши на `TabItem` - `System.NullReferenceException: "Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта."`

Comment: Очевидно что sender не есть Figure_M

Comment: @АндрейNOP Да, это я уже понял. Спасибо! Но как можно получить координаты мыши с конкретного шаблона `DataTemplate` ? Я получаю координаты общие с `TabItem`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Пожалуйста, посмотри видео - https://youtu.be/wy6n9v3klEY

Comment: Можно поставить брейкпоинт на `sender as Figure_M` и узнать, что же там на самом деле в `sender`. А там...внезапно `TabControl`, а всё потому, что контрол, вызывающий событие и есть "отправитель", и в `sender` он всегда передает себя. Следовательно вам нужно `TabControl tc = sender as TabControl`, и дальше уже копать, что же там внутри. Ну или вешать обработчик события на более подходящий контрол, чтобы внутри уже работать с ним.